# jquery datepicker on jquery dialog won't work after server validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Have anyone encountered the issue on jquery's datepicker loaded on jquery's dialog where jquery datepicker won't work after server validation?

Example: I have a button which load jquery dialog on click. On dialog open event I have the ff code:

```
if ($('input.date-picker').length > 0) { //has datepicker element            
            $('input.date-picker').attr("readonly", "readonly");
            $('input.date-picker').datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
            });
        }
```

It works perfectly on first load and client side validation. However I have certain business requirement that I need to check on the server side. Example I have 2 dates and date1 should be > date2. When this condition is not satisfied it returns an error and reload the view on the dialog. But this time the jquery datepicker did not load. The clickable datepicker image did not render.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AJAX to reload the contents of the view from the server then when this AJAX succeeds as you are recreating the DOM you will need to reattach the datepicker. For example let's suppose that you have AJAXified the form contained in this dialog like this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.url,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $('#someid').html(result);

            // reattach the datepicker
            // TODO: put this in a separate function to avoid
            // repeating it
            if ($('input.date-picker').length > 0) {
                $('input.date-picker').attr("readonly", "readonly");
                $('input.date-picker').datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
               });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and if you are using the built-in `Ajax.BeginForm` helpers then you could perform this in the `OnSuccess` function that you would subscribe to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but it didn't work. Note that I'm loading the form in the dialog box. I'll try to customized a property that will compare 2 dates.

Comment: @czetsuya, yes I understand that you are loading the form in the dialog box. What I don't understand is whether you are submitting this form using an AJAX call to the server and then reloading the contents of the dialog with the returned partial from the server. If this is the case you will need to reattach the datepicker in the success event of this AJAX call.

Comment: sorry for that. I'm not using ajax when submitting the form in the modal dialog box. I'm using the code from here: http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/asp-net-mvc-ajax-dialog-form-using-jquery-ui/. As you can see in the code it manually submit the form. Seems like I'm getting closer by modifying the DialogForm.js

Comment: @czetsuya, of course that you are using AJAX. Look at the `wireUpForm` function. It AJAXifies your form. Notice how in the success callback it reattaches the unobtrusive validation using the ` $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(dialog)` call. It is exactly where you should reattach your datepickers as well.

Comment: thanks again. I was able to successfully attached the datepicker adding the code in the else part. However after that when I corrected the values the save/submit button won't fire up. I tried putting the code before or after this line: $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(dialog);